# Recommended Version for Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: versions, osx

I am wanting to download and learn how to use Blender at home on my Macintosh PowerPC system.  It is older so I need to know what version of Blender is recommended for my system, here are the specs:

Macintosh
Dual 2.3 GHz Power PC G5
OS X 10.5.8
2 Gb DDR2 SDRAM

Video Card:
NVIDIA GeForce 6600
VRAM - 256MB
32 Bit Color Depth

Comment: The latest is generally the best. Just get 2.72b

Answer (score 4):

General hardware age isn't the big problem here, and that's what the other commenters were talking about. Their advice is great if you have an x86 system of that vintage (ex, Pentium 4), but you don't. You have a PowerPC machine. That's problematic as the official OS X Blender builds are not compiled for PPC and haven't been for quite some time. Since 2.63, to be exact. You can find it here: http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.63/

Download the file blender-2.63a-release-OSX_10.5_ppc.zip and install as usual. It should be your best bet.

Comment: There is a chance you can use a newer version but you will have to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to just start with 2.72 and see if that works. This would be the fastest version of Blender currently because of optimizations. If that doesn't work for you, try starting with 2.61 (the first version with cycles) and work up the different versions.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, 2.72 is the best until we get updated again.

Comment: Blender 2.7x does not work for OP because support for PowerPC CPUs was dropped since 2.63

Comment: I read the other answer. My answer was based off of my experiences when I was starting out, and Blender 2.66 (the current version at the time) wasn't working.